# How do I change which Jenkins job is launched on Gitlab merge request?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I use Gitlab and need to change which job runs on merge request pipeline.
Currently one job runs with status icon showing on merge request with hyperlink to Jenkins job.

I need to use a new job now. This job is configured to trigger on merge request with Gitlab plugin.

And I unticked the checkbox for the old job.

However, nothing happens on new merge requests.

I went to Settings -> Webhooks in Gitlab but there was none, I tried to add one with the URL of the new Jenkins job, and the job triggers successfully but does not appear on the merge request in Gitlab.

What setup did allow this old job to run and display status information on the merge request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing step on the Jenkins job was:

```
Publish build status to GitLab
```

> Send build result to GitLab. It will be visible in the commit and/or
> merge request UI as appropriate. You must have at least one GitLab
> connection/server configured in the Jenkins global configuration. If
> you have more than one, select the appropriate one from the 'GitLab
> connection' dropdown menu in the job configuration.